# Bitmap Image on Border not updating in UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where images are downloaded from a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem().
 In the UI, I have a DispatcherTimer, that checks a folder where the images are supposed to be cached, and if found, it is suppose to show them as backgrounds for two Border elements and a Button element.

I can see the files getting downloaded to the filePath and I can step through the code where it creates the BitmapImage object, but I do not see anything rendered on the screen.

The relevant code is pasted below..

```
<Border x:Name="leftImage"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="220"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="99">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource LeftArrow}"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,0,0,0" />
</Border>
<Border x:Name="rightImage"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Height="220"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="99"
        Grid.Column="2">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource RightArrow}"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,0,10,0" />
</Border>
<Button x:Name="center"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="400"
        Height="220" />
```

---

```
//ShowImage is being called via DispatcherTimer every 5 seconds
private void ShowImage(int p, int b)
        {
            if (p < 0 || p > Model.HomeCarouselItems.Count - 1) return;
            var filePath = //FilePath 
            if (File.Exists(filePath) && !Utils.IsFileLocked(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(filePath,UriKind.Absolute);
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            bitmapImage.Freeze();
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 1:
                        leftImage.Background = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bitmapImage };

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        rightImage.Background = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = bitmapImage };

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        center.Content = new Image() { Source = bitmapImage };

                        break;
                }
            }


        }
```

Can someone please take a look and help me understand what I am doing wrong here..

Comment: Just a note: the `NotifyPropertyChanged` calls are useless as neither the changed elements are properties (but field instead), nor have they actually changed their value. The UI update should work just by setting their `Background` or `Content`. Have you set breakpoints at the `Background` or `Content` assignments to make sure that the code is actually executed?

Comment: @Clemens - Does this by any chance have to do with BitmapImage Freeze() property. I do not fully understand that, but should I try to use that instead?

Comment: A Freeze call would be necessary if the BitmapImage was created in another thread. It would however do no harm when called in the UI thread. What about my question, are the assignments actually executed?

Comment: I changed it to do a Freeze(), but still no luck..

Comment: Currently you are still ignoring my question, and also the hint given by Jeroen. Sorry, but this way you won't get help.

Comment: @Clemens - sorry..Yes, I can step through the code and see the bitmapImage object getting created. I changed the implementation as suggested by Jeroen to use absolute path. I verified that the file actually exists in that location as well.

Comment: Still you're saying that the BitmapImage is created, but is it actually *assigned* to the Background or Content, I mean does execution really enter one of the case statements? And does the `filePath` variable really contain the absolute path of the image file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35006/discussion-between-sharath-and-clemens)

Answer (score -1):

NotifyPropertyChanged() only works on properties.

I think the image cannot be found at filePath, thats why you won't see anything.

Comment: The file is present, I can step through the code and see the bitmapimage object being created correctly. I have INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented in my control, so that does not seem to be a issue..

Comment: I can enter a invalid Uri on the BitmapImage constructor without getting a exception. So the image is loaded on assigning it to the Background property. (the border will load the image) And again: <Border x:Name="rightImage" isn't a property of you control. I still think, even the image is present the image cannot be loaded due incorrect path/uri.. (try the absolute path)

Comment: I changed it to Freeze() the bitmapImage and also use Absolute URI. Still no luck..

Comment: What happens if you put the file in the cache directory and put the Uri (filePath) directly into the xaml ? <Border x:Name="leftImage" Background = <Fill-in abosulute Uri>  />   Something like that..

Comment: Putting the filePath directly in the XAML works...
 <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\\Users\\Sharath\\AppData\\Roaming\\test\\Library-How-To-Homepage4.png" />
                </Border.Background>